# Accessing the first object in a tuple using terraform

Tags: json, terraform

I am trying to access the first key on a given tuple. The key's name is dynamic and may change so it cannot be accessed using a static value and has to be done either through a for loop or through the use of terraform fuctions.

I've created a small local resource that outputs the following section

```
skip_empty_mails = { for key, value in local.j.settings.tasks : key => value.email_notifications if value.email_notifications != {} }
```

The output sent back is

```
{
  "3" = {
    "on_start" = [
      "foo1@aligntech.com",
      "foo2@aligntech.com",
      "foo3@aligntech.com",
      "foo4@aligntech.com",
    ]
  }
  "4" = {
    "no_alert_for_skipped_runs" = false
    "on_start" = [
      "foo21@aligntech.com",
      "foo22@aligntech.com",
      "foo23@aligntech.com",
      "foo24@aligntech.com",
    ]
    ]
    "on_start" = [
      "foo21@aligntech.com",
      "foo22@aligntech.com",
      "foo23@aligntech.com",
      "foo24@aligntech.com",
    ]
    "on_success" = [
      "foo21@aligntech.com",
      "foo22@aligntech.com",
      "foo23@aligntech.com",
      "foo24@aligntech.com",
    ]
  }
}
```

As seen above the key that holds all the values needs to be accessed in a way that will give me the ability to attach it to a string and use `string.on_start` to pull its values.

The issue is that our key's name is dynamic and may vary.

I've tried following the [terraform function documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions) But haven't found anything that might be of use in this case.

**You may be able to replicate using the following code**

```
locals {
  json = {
      "3" = {
        "on_start" = [
          "foo1@aligntech.com",
          "foo2@aligntech.com",
          "foo3@aligntech.com",
          "foo4@aligntech.com",
        ]
      },
      "4" = {
        "no_alert_for_skipped_runs" = false
        "on_failure" = [
          "foo21@aligntech.com",
          "foo22@aligntech.com",
          "foo23@aligntech.com",
          "foo24@aligntech.com",
        ]
        "on_start" = [
          "foo21@aligntech.com",
          "foo22@aligntech.com",
          "foo23@aligntech.com",
          "foo24@aligntech.com",
        ]
        "on_success" = [
          "foo1@foo.com",
          "foo2@foo.com",
          "foo3@foo.com",
          "foo4@foo.com",
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with a combination of `values`, `element` or `flatten` see the documentation:

- https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/values
- https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/element
- https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/flatten

Below are samples:

---

> #### First key extraction

```hcl
locals {
  json = {
      "4" = {
        "no_alert_for_skipped_runs" = false
        "on_failure" = [
          "foo1@foo.com",
          "foo2@foo.com",
        ]
        "on_start" = [
          "foo1@foo.com",
          "foo2@foo.com",
        ]
    }
  }
}

output "data" {
    value = element(values(local.json), 1).on_start
}
```

the Terraform plan will be:

```txt
Changes to Outputs:
  + data = [
      + "foo1@foo.com",
      + "foo2@foo.com",
    ]
```

---

> #### Extract and combine on_start item from all

```hcl
locals {
  json = {
      "3" = {
        "on_start" = [
          "foo1@aligntech.com",
          "foo2@aligntech.com",
        ]
      },
      "4" = {
        "on_start" = [
          "foo1@foo.com",
          "foo2@foo.com",
        ]
    }
  }
}

output "data" {
    value = flatten(values(local.json)[*].on_start)
}
```

the Terraform plan will be:

```txt
Changes to Outputs:
  + data = [
      + "foo1@aligntech.com",
      + "foo2@aligntech.com",
      + "foo1@foo.com",
      + "foo2@foo.com",
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser but this is not the solution I was looking for. I have updated my original question to show another usecase of multiple `email_notifications` instead of a single section. Your solution will only pull a single `email_notifications` field instead all of them.

Comment: @Elazar I modified the answer to consider your new example

Comment: @Elazar to be clear, in your question you said first object (that is a single item) there is no mention of multiple items there, anyone reading your question will not be able to figure out what you want ... in the future keep your examples short but cover all cases you looking for, also include what you expect your output to look like

Comment: It is stated in the question - `The key's name is dynamic and may change so it cannot be accessed using a static value`

Comment: Yes key name can be dynamic, that is not a problem, but if you ask for the first object that  is a single item not multiple ... but my second example cover the new case, the code is simple `flatten(values(local.json)[*].on_start)`

Comment: Thank you for refining your anwser. Could you please update the original post? I'll accept it as the anwser.